# Visual Studio 2017 (Community) and SQL Server 2017 incompatible?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

When I try to attach my database to Visual Studio 2017 I get this error, could anyone help me?

[image]

I'm running everything as 2017

- Visual Studio Community 2017
- SQL Server Express 2017
- SQL Server Management Studio 2017
- SQL Server Configuration Manager 2017

And also, how may I open the Command Prompt of my SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server version 852 is for SQL Server 2016, so it looks like you installed SQL Server Local DB when installing Visual Studio, as the version of SQL that gets shipped with VS2016 is SQL 2016.

Since you've installed SQL Server 2017, then I suggest that you uninstall Local DB from your machine, as you probably don't need both. This post describes the steps required. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e067d1e-a5c2-49d6-b096-2879f2df97ff/how-to-uninstall-localdb-2016?forum=sqlexpress